# How to create asynchronous "cron like" scheduler inside nginx

Tags: dictionary, nginx, lua, cron, redis

I need to create an asynchronous scheduler inside `nginx` server to update a variable. Let me give you an example what I mean by this and why I need it.

Imagine config file that looks something like this:

```
http {
    lua_shared_dict foo 5m;
    server {
        location /set {
            content_by_lua '
                local foo = ngx.shared.foo
                ngx.say(foo:get("12345"))
            ';
        }
    }
}
```

I specified variable `foo` that resides in shared memory and all worker processes have access to it. What I want to do is to set those values from `lua` script that will be called every minite. Just for reference it will be going to the `Redis` and then retrieve necessary data, and update this variable. I know I can do this in `content_by_lua` in every call, but it's highly inefficient for a huge volume of traffic.

I would like a separate process that would be triggered every minute or so to just go and one task. Is there anything like this in `nginx` or are there any modules that could help me with that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the new ngx.timer API provided by ngx_lua. See the documentation for details:

https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/modules/lua/#ngx-timer-at

You can create a new timer in your timer handler to make the timer keeps triggering like a cronjob ;)

BTW, the timer is per-worker process, you can use the lua-resty-lock library in your timer handler to ensure that only one timer is active at a time among all the nginx workers: https://github.com/agentzh/lua-resty-lock

Answer (score 1):

You can use [ngx.timer.every](https://github.com/openresty/lua-nginx-module#ngxtimerevery) API. Using [ngx.timer.every](https://github.com/openresty/lua-nginx-module#ngxtimerevery) API is recommended over using recursive [ngx.timer.at](https://github.com/openresty/lua-nginx-module#ngxtimerat) API.